# Take screenshot from iOS simulator and use it in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My iOS simulator is using the large image setting in its preferences:
[image]

Then I save the current screen via the camera icon button on top of my simulator:
[image]

But when I upload the screenshot to App Connect Store for my app release, I always get this error:
[image]

How to get rid of this issue so that my screenshot from simulator can be used for App Store Connect? (imaging that I am a developer not a UI designer)

Answer (score 4):

The 5.5" display size is for the iPhone 6s+ family, while you're taking a screenshot from the iPhone 11 device family. Use different emulators for different device families.

Screen size references: https://iosref.com/res

Answer (score 2):

In xcode I used Product > Run to start the simulator and took screenshots with the button on the upper right of the simulator

Then I installed imagemagick

```
brew update && brew install imagemagick
```

and converted the pictures to the right format

```
for i in ~/Desktop/*.png; do convert "$i" -resize 1242x2688 -background black -gravity center -extent 1242x2688 "${i/img/imgResized}"; done
```